# Git- Reverting previous 2 pushed commits

Tags: git, github

I commited a change 10 days ago, which had 3 files and pushed them.I raised a PR #46 and  it was not yet merged.

Today i had to change 1 more file, when i commited and pushed, it went to the same PR #46.

Now, i dont want to the 3 old files in PR #46 to get merged, instead only want the today's commit to be merged into remote.

I checked online, and saw "Git revert hash" is an option.

I tried

git revert c12345d --no-edit.    --> today's commit

and

git revert 212345f --no-edit.    --> 10 days back commit

and

I also closed the #PR46

Even after doing the above, it still shows the files in the GITHUB UI when i try to see the Pull Requests page, and in the command line, it still says

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Can someone help me where i did wrong?

Basically, i only want today's change to be pushed and created a PR and merged.

Comment: To see the two revert commits on GitHub, you must push the branch. Why not just open a new PR?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do what you want. The one that I would use (because simpler if you're not very familiar with Git) would be:

- create a new branch of your main branch
- cherry-pick the commit you want (it's like "copy pasting" a commit from a branch to another)
- push this new branch and open a new PR

```sh
git checkout mainbranch
git checkout -b newbranch
git cherry-pick c12345d # "today's commit" hash
git push
```